# Создание на WPF графического редактора

Tags: c#, wpf

Можно ли, используя **технологию WPF**, в C# создать полноценный графический редактор
с сохранением картинок и анимации? В каком формате можно сохранить анимацию?

Answer (score 3):

Если в основе редактора будут сущности WPF, то и сохранить их можно будет только в XAML. Штатными средствами отрендерить сцену (xaml) в картинку можно, но это будет, разумеется, статическая картинка. Похоже, что подобные редакторы существуют, я нагуглил один [create-xaml-vector-graphics-easily](http://www.worthytips.com/4555/create-xaml-vector-graphics-easily.html)

Answer (score 2):

В WPF можно, но нужно также учесть, что анимация, по-моему, там сделана карявенько.
А пиксельные эффекты можно тоже в редактор добавить (смешивание картинок и эффекты), но это достаточно сложно (для меня). В общем не могу себе представить полноценный граф. редактор без эффектов. А анимация там - жуть

Answer (score 1):

Интерфейс Microsoft Expression Blend (а это практически полноценный графический редактор) создан на основе WPF. Так что да, редактор вполне можно создать. Векторные картинки и анимации можно хранить в XAML (а возможно и в SVG).